# My integral is not giving me any output

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I have put this equation into mathematica but I don't seem to get an output,
please help!

```
Integrate[(1/(Pi*Sqrt[1-x^2]))*(1/(Pi*Sqrt[1-(z-x)^2])),{x,-1,1}]
```

Comment: If Mathematica returns your input to you unchanged, it means that it does not know the answer. It may be that an answer does not exist. A lot of integrals do not have a closed form expression.

Answer (score 1):

Your integrand does not behave well at x = +/-1. A plot shows that you have problems

```
Plot3D[(1/(Pi*Sqrt[1 - x^2]))*(1/(Pi*Sqrt[1 - (z - x)^2])),
 {x, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1},
 PlotRange -> {All, All, {0, 500}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If we concentrate on z = 0

```
Plot[(1/(Pi*Sqrt[1 - x^2]))*(1/(Pi*Sqrt[1 - (0 - x)^2])), {x, -1, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Let's try integrating with z = 0 and not going to +/- 1. We get an answer

```
int0 = Integrate[
  Evaluate[(1/(Pi*Sqrt[1 - x^2]))*(1/(Pi*Sqrt[1 - (z - x)^2])) /. 
    z -> 0], {x, -a, a}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

We can take the limit as a goes to 1 but it is clear what is going to happen

Limit[int0[[1]], a -> 1]

(*  ∞   *)

Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

Using [Rubi](https://rulebasedintegration.org) package we have:

```
<< Rubi`
SOL = FullSimplify[Int[(1/(Pi*Sqrt[1 - x^2]))*(1/(Pi*Sqrt[1 - (z - x)^2])), x], 
Assumptions -> {-1 <= x <= 1, z > 0}]

(*(2 Sqrt[1/(2 + z - z^2)] Sqrt[2 + z - z^2]
EllipticF[ArcSin[Sqrt[((1 + x - z) z)/((-1 + x - z) (-2 + z))]], 
1 - 4/z^2])/(\[Pi]^2 z)*)

(SOL /. x -> 1) - (SOL /. x -> -1) // Simplify(*Solution for z > 0*)
(*(2 Sqrt[1/(2 + z - z^2)] Sqrt[2 + z - z^2] (-EllipticF[ArcSin[Sqrt[z^2/(-4 + z^2)]], 1 - 4/z^2] + 
EllipticK[1 - 4/z^2]))/(\[Pi]^2 z)*)


HoldForm[Integrate[(1/(Pi*Sqrt[1 - x^2]))*(1/(Pi*Sqrt[1 - (z - x)^2])), {x, -1, 1}] == (
2 Sqrt[1/(2 + z - z^2)] Sqrt[2 + z - z^2] (-EllipticF[ArcSin[Sqrt[z^2/(-4 + z^2)]], 
    1 - 4/z^2] + EllipticK[1 - 4/z^2]))/(\[Pi]^2 z)] // TeXForm
```

TeXForm code:

$$\int_{-1}^1 \frac{1}{\left(\pi  \sqrt{1-x^2}\right) \left(\pi  \sqrt{1-(z-x)^2}\right)} \, dx=\frac{2 \sqrt{\frac{1}{2+z-z^2}} \sqrt{2+z-z^2}
   \left(-F\left(\sin ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{z^2}{-4+z^2}}\right)|1-\frac{4}{z^2}\right)+K\left(1-\frac{4}{z^2}\right)\right)}{\pi ^2 z}$$

for:$z>0$